# Same code being packaged to different targets

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

All,
practical question. 1 app entirely developed in native (for eg. iOS), can be packaged for another platform (eg. Android) just because it's using Mobilefirst libraries? Like cross compile something from iOS to Android without manual intervention?

For hybrid applications understood is possible to generate from the same piece of code because it's using HTML5 + cordova to generate targeted builds with cordova's "restrictions".

On both scenarios Mobilefirst back end services will be used the same - thru adapters.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

How? applicaive code for iOS is written in Objective-C or Swift. Android apps are written in Java? It's got nothing to do with MobileFirst. MobileFirst provides separate SDKs - one for Android and one for iOS, they are not "interchangeable" nor cross-compiable.